# Issues with MATLAB: JPEG2000 compression scheme using wavelet toolbox

Tags: image, matlab, wavelet

Me and a teammate are working on a JPEG2000 similar compression scheme for a project.  It utilizes matlab and the wavelet toolbox.

There are 2 problems.  My lack of knowledge with JPEG2000 leads me to believe I am missing steps for this compression process.  The 2nd problem is an actual error which involves: `[dict,avglen] = huffmandict(cQ,p); % Create dictionary.`
Error:
??? Error using ==> huffmandict at 174
Source symbols repeat

I am not sure if this has to do with repeating values in the matrix because no run-length coding has been done.

Error in ==> project at 41
[dict,avglen] = huffmandict(cQ,p); % Create dictionary.

Any tips or information would be beneficial.
Also, I am unsure whether I need a pre-processing step

The code is as follows:

```
%wavelet based compression sub-band coding
clear all;
close all;
x=imread('1.png');%input image
n=input('enter the desired decompositon level '); %decompositon level
Q=input('enter the desired quantization step size '); %quantization level

%begin wavelet decomposition
c = [];
sx =  size(x);
s = zeros(n+2,length(sx));
if isempty(x) , return; end

s(end,:) = size(x);
for i=1:n
    [x,h,v,d] = dwt2(x,'haar'); % decomposition
    c = [h(:)' v(:)' d(:)' c];     % store details
    s(n+2-i,:) = size(x);          % store size
end

% Last approximation.
c = [x(:)' c];
s(1,:) = size(x);

%Begin Quantization

cQ=round(c/Q);

%Begin Entropy Encoding



scQ=length(cQ);
l=1;
for i=1:(scQ-1);
    l=l/2;
    p(i)=l;
end
p(scQ)=p(scQ-1);

[dict,avglen] = huffmandict(cQ,p); % Create dictionary.
actualsig = randsrc(100,1,[cQ; p]); % Create data using p.
comp = huffmanenco(actualsig,dict); % Encode the data.
```

Comment: Update: we are not allowed to use the wcompress function.

Answer (score -1):

I know that it is only a partial answer, but it appears that the error is caused because your input contains duplicates.

This can be prevented by using the `unique` command.

On [this website](http://www.techques.com/question/1-11196481/MATLAB---image-huffman-encoding) they recommend something like:

```
[symbols,p]=hist(A,double(unique(A)))
```

But as I am not sure how your input works, you may need to use

```
unique([cQ; p],'rows')
```